# Authorising users in an ASP.NET (MVC5) web api project

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Ok, so I'm struggling a little bit with trying to get a authentication process in my ASP.NET MVC5 (Web API 2) project. To start, here are some requirements:

- I can't use Entity Framework (all access to the DB needs to be done through stored procedures)
- Needs to target .NET Framework 4.5.2
- I am not using ASP.NET Core
- I would like to be able to use Bearer (or similar) tokens for authentication
- I would like to invalidate tokens if a user logs out or automatically invalidate them after 24 hours
- I would like to pass (and receive) XML when sending requests to the "login" (or "token") endpoint (note that ideally the solution should respect the "Content-Type" and "Accepts" headers, so if I send it JSON it should respond in JSON, and if I send it XML it should respond in XML)
- I will not be using external providers (e.g. Google) anytime soon (maybe never)
- I would like to use the `<Authorize>` attributes to help with protecting other endpoints
- I am using VB.NET, although answers to this question can be in C# (I can convert them or rewrite them to suit)
- I would like to store the tokens in the database so I can record which user is doing what within the API

(note that there are lots of reasons why I can't change the above)

I've tried to do this with Owin (OAuth) but I've found the following issues when comparing this to the requirements:

- I can't seem to send the token endpoint any XML
- Responses from the authentication endpoints (both successful and unsuccessful) are in JSON
- I can't invalidate the tokens when logging out

I am happy to move away from OAuth if that is the best way to go for what I want. I would prefer to use Microsoft built nuget packages (ie no third party solutions) or I'm happy to partially roll my own solution (I would like to leverage as much of in-built or Microsoft built code, including Identity and Claims as possible so I can minimise testing efforts).

I have read numerous StackOverflow questions about this and search heaps on the internet, but most articles stick with OAuth despite the above issues or they rely on EntityFramework. My current solution uses the code from here (pretty much copy/pasted with some custom code in ApplicationOAuthProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()): https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1187872/Token-Based-Authentication-for-Web-API-where-Legac

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can access stored procedures through Entity Framework. What particular problem are you having? My understanding is that .Net Authorisation is not tied to entity framework (not in my experience). Can't really help with the rest but it would certainly be advantageous if you could post some code and indicate where it goes wrong

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks - fair point regarding Entity Framework, but I'm unsure where to start with it in regards to stored procedures (I'll look that up separately). I said that more as a point that most resources/tutorials go straight into using EntityFramework, which is a little bit unhelpful at this stage. Unfortunately (fortunately?) the code works fine but the needed features (invalidating tokens, storing tokens, using XML) can't be achieved from what I can tell. Are there any other authentication methods that I can look into?

Comment: Is it worth trying to address your outstanding issues with OAuth one by one? If they could be overcome, perhaps it's an option? For example in my research to understand this better I came across this page https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1205160/ASP-NET-Core-Bearer-Authentication which has it's own custom controller providing the token. So it would seem that you can write your own token endpoint that accepts and returns XML. I'm kinda out of my depth here but I usually find I learn something if I try to help solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more extensive research and it looks like OAuth is not applicable for my specific situation. Although it seems like a nice authentication method, I really need to invalidate tokens via the DB, and I need the API to always send/receive XML (these are apparently not applicable when using OAuth).

To solve these problems, I have rolled my own token-based solution that creates a hashed token on the client side, so I never send passwords over the wire (which is a little bit nicer) because the token is generated on the client side (note that I am controlling what happens on the client side - these are all in house clients and I am writing the libraries these clients will use). This involved me creating my own filter which inherits `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`.

If anyone stumbles across this question and provides a really good answer, I'm more than happy to mark theirs as accepted.